# Import XLSX file in SAS starting from the third row, using other option than RANGE

Tags: sas

We can import an XLS file using namerow and startrow, like in this example :

```
%let dir_n=TheDir_name;
%let fichimp=file_name.xls;

PROC IMPORT DATAFILE= "&dir_n.\&file_name."
                        out=want
                        dbms=xls replace;
            sheet=theSheet_name;
            getnames=no;
            namerow=2;
            startrow=3;
run;
```

I have read : To import XLSX file, use RANGE if the data is not starting on the first line.

Is there similar option to STARTROW to import XLSX file starting from a specific row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not.  `dbms=XLSX` only has a limited set of options, listed [in the documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acpcref/69731/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0msy4hy1so0ren1acm90iijxn8j.htm): `GETNAMES`, `SHEET`, and `RANGE`.

`EXCEL` has a few more options (including `DBDSOPTS` which opens up several database-type options), but still uses `range` to control what is read in.